# Unable to move button in Android Studio in linearlayout

Tags: xml, android-studio

I've never faced problem like this, tried many things before I actually asked question here.
So basically, this new button I created is like fixed onto top of the screen and it doesn't want to move. When I try to move it, after I remove my finger from right click it again sticks to top.

Picture of design:

[image]

And this is XML code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/loginregister"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I make it move?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with the following code, by changing "gravity to center" and making it to "follow" parent element.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:background="@drawable/loginregister"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:text="@string/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```